# How to get headers names from json data | python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert json data to csv and I was able to do

But one main problem is I need to hard code my headers in list ... how to get automatically headers and even i am passing - `jsdata['clients']`  -> client hardcoded

**Need to make generic the headers and client which I am passing**

**Code :**

```
import json
import csv 

header = ["id","isActive","age","name","gender","company","email","phone","address"]
with open('/content/sample_data/ABC.json') as rd:
  jsdata = json.loads(rd.read())
  with open('/content/sample_data/Ts.csv','w') as wr:
    csv_wr = csv.DictWriter(wr,fieldnames=header)
    csv_wr.writeheader()
    csv_wr.writerows(jsdata['clients'])
```

**Following is my json data**

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "id": "59761c23b30d971669fb42ff",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 36,
      "name": "Dunlap Hubbard",
      "gender": "male",
      "company": "CEDWARD",
      "email": "dunlaphubbard@cedward.com",
      "phone": "+1 (890) 543-2508",
      "address": "169 Rutledge Street, Konterra, Northern Mariana Islands, 8551"
    },
    {
      "id": "59761c233d8d0f92a6b0570d",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 24,
      "name": "Kirsten Sellers",
      "gender": "female",
      "company": "EMERGENT",
      "email": "kirstensellers@emergent.com",
      "phone": "+1 (831) 564-2190",
      "address": "886 Gallatin Place, Fannett, Arkansas, 4656"
    },
    {
      "id": "59761c23fcb6254b1a06dad5",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 30,
      "name": "Acosta Robbins",
      "gender": "male",
      "company": "ORGANICA",
      "email": "acostarobbins@organica.com",
      "phone": "+1 (882) 441-3367",
      "address": "697 Linden Boulevard, Sattley, Idaho, 1035"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: *jsdata = json.load(rd)* is more concise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every dictionary within the clients list has the same keys then...

```
csv_wr = csv.DictWriter(wr,fieldnames=jsdata['clients'][0])
```

Comment: Is their any way to replace the jsdata['Client']  -> some index '

Comment: Difference between load and loads

Comment: @nodehep223 Why would you want to do that? There's only only key at the top level of your JSON structure and it's called 'clients'. Or are you looking for a technique for acquiring the key name?

Comment: @nodehep223 *loads* loads from a string *load* loads from a file handle

Comment: Yes i original file will have client1 ,client 2 , client 3  how to get that keys

Comment: @nodehep223 jsdata.keys()